Rate of the variance decrease in the elbow plot of K-means clustering
Say there are $k$ points $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$, let $f(n)$ be the minimum within-cluster variance with $n$ cluster centroids, that is
$$
f(n)=\min_{\{\mu_1,...\mu_n\}}\sum_{i=1}^k\min_{j\in[n]}\|x_i-\mu_j\|^2.
$$
Of course we have that $0=f(k)\le f(k-1)\le ...\le f(1)$. Is it correct that $f(k-1)-f(k)\ge f(k)-f(k+1)$?
